# R: how to add copyright notices for dependencies?

Tags: r, cran

When creating an R package and hosting it in CRAN, the licensing of the package is typically communicated by:

- Adding a field `License` in the `DESCRIPTION` file with the name of the license, provided that it is among the typical open source licenses recognized by R - e.g.:

`License: GPL (>=3)`

- For licenses with a copyright notice, adding instead the name of the license plus a file called `LICENSE` indicating the year and author - e.g.

`License: MIT + file LICENSE`
And then the file LICENSE containing this:

```
YEAR: 2021
COPYRIGHT HOLDER: Me
```

This is fine when the package does not include any dependencies, but now suppose I want to ship a few depencies **within the source code of a package**, each of which will imply different notices and copyright holders.

For example, assume the package is being distributed under, say, MIT or GPL, and then there is one dependency with a BSD 2-clause, and another dependency with a MIT license, each of which is from different authors and years which differ from the main package's.

To clarify, this question is about how to properly structure the files `DESCRIPTION`, `LICENSE`, and `COPYRIGHTS` in such a way that they'd result in something that (a) is a valid R package (would install, check, and load without errors or warnings), (b) would be accepted by CRAN, (c) would comply with the license (that is: should include a copyright notice in both source and binary builds of the package).

(As an aside, I browsed a few packages in CRAN that ship dependencies under their source code and noticed that the license of the dependencies is oftentimes ignored - e.g. a package is GPL, includes MIT code, but the MIT copyright notice is completely missing from the source package save for what's at the top of the source file. This other answer would break the terms of BSD licenses when distributing binary packages: [Properly License R Package that Includes Other MIT Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525023/properly-license-r-package-that-includes-other-mit-code))

The R extensions manual mentions the following:

- """If a package license restricts a base license (where permitted, e.g., using GPL-3 or AGPL-3 with an attribution clause), the additional terms should be placed in file LICENSE (or LICENCE), and the string ‘+ file LICENSE’ (or ‘+ file LICENCE’, respectively) should be appended to the corresponding individual license specification."""
- """An optional ‘Copyright’ field can be used where the copyright holder(s) are not the authors. If necessary, this can refer to an installed file: the convention is to use file inst/COPYRIGHTS."""
- """Another file sometimes needed in inst is AUTHORS or COPYRIGHTS to specify the authors or copyright holders when this is too complex to put in the DESCRIPTION file."""

But I'm not sure how to interpret those statements.

- In the first case, if the package and the dependency have the same license, does that count as "restricting"? If not, am I supposed to copy-paste the full copyright notice from e.g. a MIT license into the file `LICENSE`? should that come after I specify my own copyright year and name?
- In the second and third cases, if I do have copyright over most of the code, how am I supposed to signal this into the copyright field? Or is this a free-text file? If this file is under `inst`, how should the entry look like in the `DESCRIPTION` file? is it fine to just specify the license for the main package code?

Comment: Are you asking for legal advice? This isn't really a specific question about programming. Perhaps contact those who wrote the code to see what their expectations are. This isn't really a question that would appear to have one answer for all possible cases. This seems to be [off topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing)

Comment: @MrFlick : I'm asking about the structure of the license and description files which need to be present in an R package for it to be valid.

Comment: It would be more helpful to give a specific example. Show what you tried. `R CMD check` should look for problems with packages and report them to you. Are you worried about CRAN requirements, R requirements, or legal requirements for the license? If things are unclear and you are worried about CRAN specifically, contact the [R-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel) mailing list if you are worried that you are unable to declare a license type that's appropriate for your package. Does "valid" just mean R can load it?

Comment: Thanks, edited a bit the question, however R CMD does not catch all the CRAN intricacies - e.g. assuming no dependencies, if I copy the full text of a MIT license to file `LICENSE` and add `License: MIT + file LICENSE`, that's fine for R CMD, but is not fine for CRAN.